# Print out salt using mcrypt

Tags: php, crypt

I am trying to get a salt value printed out. For this i use the following code, but nothing happens when i run this script. I have check php.ini for mcrypt and its installed and works.

```
<?php
    class Hash {
        public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
            return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
        }

        public static function salt($length) {
            return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
        }

        public static function unique() {
            return self::make(uniqid());
        }
    }

    echo 'print out salt';
    echo $salt = Hash::salt(32);
    die();
```

Comment: Most likely, you are missing a required extension and you haven't configured PHP to display error messages.

Comment: "but nothing happens" surely *something* is happening. Enable error reporting / debug your code

Comment: Worked fine for me `print out salt×]ÒLŸJn%M´“ÎîÇÙÐ :=UuRÎObß`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Might be the version of PHP you're using. Error reporting may throw `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()...`

Comment: Have enable display_errors = on in php config and restarted apache etc.. Its only print out salt.. Tried to use php -l filename.php to se syntax error and it shows no syntax errors..

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The problem was with mcrypt line 12 .. Fixed this error with "sudo php5enmod mcrypt" and then restart apache server "sudo service apache2 restart". Thanks again guys!

Comment: If you answered your own question, either add the answer below and accept it, or delete the question please.

Comment: @j08691 will do that, new to the site. Sorry for that. But it's fixed now. thanks Fred -ii-,  Álvaro G. Vicario and PeeHaa

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with mcrypt line 12.

I fixed this error with: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` then restarting the Apache server with: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Another happy ending ;)

Comment: To clarify: that's a command used by certain Linux distros (namely Debian and family) to enable a PHP extension for the Apache module. Thus actual problem was that mcrypt wasn't installed and either PHP wasn't configured to throw error messages or you couldn't find them (e.g. you didn't check the server logs). In general, how to install PHP extensions depends entirely on the platform and, of course, your mcrypt code does not require a web server at all.